# how to remove deprecation on doctrine AbstractFixture::getReference()

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, fixtures, deprecation-warning

In PHPUnit 10,
I have somes fixtures between entities and they share references.
I have the following deprecation and i can't manage to remove it :

```
Argument $class of Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture::getReference() will be mandatory in 2.0. (AbstractFixture.php:95 called by ProductFixture.php:26, https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/409, package doctrine/data-fixtures)
```

here is my code, and the different step to trying to remove the deprecation but this get an exception

```
class ProductFamilyFixture extends Fixture
{
    public const PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE = 'PRODUCTS_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE';

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        //*******************************************
        //ProductsFamilies

        $entity = new ProductsFamilies();
        $entity->setDesignation('Famille1');
        $manager->persist($entity);

        $entity2 = new ProductsFamilies();
        $entity2->setDesignation('Famille2');
        $manager->persist($entity2);

        $this->addReference(self::PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE, $entity);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}


    class ProductFixture extends Fixture  implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public const PRODUCT_1_REFERENCE = 'PRODUCT_1_REFERENCE';

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        //*******************************************

        $entity = new Products();
        $entity->setPn('Pn1')
            ->setDesignation('Désignation produit1')
            ->setPrefix('Pr')
            // work but send deprecation !!
            ->setFamily($this->getReference(ProductFamilyFixture::PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE)); 

            // This  doesn't work => error
            //OutOfBoundsException: Reference to "PRODUCTS_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE" for class "App\DataFixtures\ProductFamilyFixture" does not exist
        
//            ->setFamily($this->getReference(ProductFamilyFixture::PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE,ProductFamilyFixture::class)); 
//            ->setFamily($this->getReference('PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE','ProductFamilyFixture'));
//            ->setFamily($this->getReference('PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE',ProductFamilyFixture::class));
//            ->setFamily($this->getReference(ProductFamilyFixture::PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE,'ProductFamilyFixture'));

        $manager->persist($entity);
        $manager->flush();

        $this->addReference(self::PRODUCT_1_REFERENCE, $entity);

    }

    public function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductFamilyFixture::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

Any idea to remove this deprecation ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the [deprecation warning](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/409) you have to set the class when using `getReference()`

```
$this->addReference($referenceName, $entity);
```

Because it's expecting your entity class as a second parameter

```
public function getReference($name, ?string $class = null)
```

Throw a deprecation warning if `$class` is null.

Just update your code with something like this:

```
->setFamily($this->getReference(ProductFamilyFixture::PRODUCT_FAMILY_1_REFERENCE, ProductFamily::class));
```

Comment: Thanks you open my eyes on my mistake. I was passing the fixture's class for reference and not the class of the entity.